# Connecting to a part of a website depending on input. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, input, connect

Im new to python and wondering if there is a way for it to open a webpage depending on whats been inputted. EG

```
Market=input("market")
ticker=input("Ticket")
```

would take you to this part of the website.

```
https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/'market'-'ticker'/technicals
```

Thanks

Comment: Please make an attempt, demonstrate that attempt and the issues you are having

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were pretty much there, but it python you can use the `+` sign to concatenate strings and then cause it to open that link using webbrowser library

```
import webbrowser
market=input("market") 
ticker=input("Ticket") 
webbrowser.open('https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/'+market+'-'+ticker+'/technicals')
```

Answer (score 0):

Its cleaner to use format string like this:

```
import webbrowser         
market=input("market")    
ticker=input("Ticket")     
webbrowser.open(f'https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/{market}-{ticker}/technicals')
```